# iPhone/iPad: When to change background on rotate of device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation, rotation

At what point in the rotation of a device should I replace the image that forms the background. There are 2 images, one for Landscape, one for Portrait.

Currently I use the WillRotate event, but it's 'choppy' in performance and I get warnings about not to do this in a two stage rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use either -

1.
`-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

Sent to the view controller before performing a one-step user interface rotation.

or

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Sent to the view controller after the user interface rotates.